# How to connect to remote directory

Tags: directory, remote

I am new to ubuntu and I need to connect to such directory for example  `\\abc.cba.com\xxx\yyy\zzz`

On windows I just simply opened it via win + r and pasted that there. How can I do something like that on ubuntu ?

Comment: What protocol do you want to use to access the Server? SSH, WebDAV, FTP, SAMBA?

Answer (score 0):

In Linux you mount the drive or can ssh the abc.cba.com server and access the machine if both the machines are Linux.

In case if you want to access windows folder in Linux then follow the below steps

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils

mkdir ~/Desktop/Windows-Share

sudo mount.cifs //WindowsPC/Share /home/user/Desktop/Windows-Share -o user=user_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Open `Files`, the archive image on your Launcher. At the bottom of the list on the left of the Files window you will see Places, Devices and Network. Under the Network tag just click `Connect to Server` and paste the path to the directory.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a NFS Server ready, you can use a NFS Client.

Follow these steps carefully: [Setting up NFS how-to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo)